# Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Tags: pi-4, kernel, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Running on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, Raspberry Pi OS 64 Lite

Error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux test-rpi 6.1.55-v8+ #1686 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct  5 15:47:38 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Sources:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main
```

More tests:

```
$ apt policy raspberrypi-kernel-headers
N: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it's working, I guess there was some maintenance going on.
If you know the reason that package wasn't available this morning please share :)

Comment: It happens quite often and thats the reason I have started to use `apt list <pkg name>` to rule out spelling errors, one possible fault ruled out.

Answer (score -1):

To verify if a package exists or not in a repository, use:

```
apt list raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

`apt list` accepts wildcards, ex:

```
apt list raspberrypi*
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, apt-get is not deprecated. No, running apt does not help. Please, revisit apt policy documentation.

Comment: Thx for your correction.